# Remove duplicate records except the first record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, duplicates

I want to remove all duplicate records except the first one.

Like :

```
NAME
R
R
rajesh
YOGESH
YOGESH
```

Now in the above I want to remove the second "R" and the second "YOGESH".

I have only one column whose name is "NAME".

Comment: remove or select unique values?

Comment: remove duplicate but only except first.

Comment: If they are the same how would you know if it is the first or not? And does it really matter? And since you have only 1 column there is no first because a table is an unordered set.

Comment: i mean want to delete but not all duplicates.

Comment: @YogeshSharma Any `Primary Key` in that table.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a CTE (I have several of these in production).

```
;WITH duplicateRemoval as (
    SELECT 
        [name]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY [name]) ranked
    from #myTable
    ORDER BY name
)
DELETE
FROM duplicateRemoval
WHERE ranked > 1;
```

**Explanation**: The CTE will grab all of your records and apply a row number for each unique entry. Each additional entry will get an incrementing number. Replace the `DELETE` with a `SELECT *` in order to see what it does.

Comment: Change the where predicate to > 1 in case there are more than 2. :)

Comment: @SeanLange you are absolutely correct - I updated that.

Comment: @Eli Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a simple `distinct` modifier would do the trick:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bigger code but it works perfectly where you don't take the original row but find all the duplicate Rows

```
    select majorTable.RowID,majorTable.Name,majorTable.Value from 
    (select outerTable.Name, outerTable.Value, RowID, ROW_NUMBER() 
over(partition by outerTable.Name,outerTable.Value order by RowID)
     as RowNo from @Your_Table outerTable inner join
    (select Name, Value,COUNT(*) as duplicateRows  FROM @Your_Table group by Name, Value 
having COUNT(*)>1)innerTable on innerTable.Name = outerTable.Name 
    and innerTable.Value = outerTable.Value)majorTable where MajorTable.ROwNo <>1
```