# how to delete duplicated value from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I had a table with some duplicate values. I have removed the duplicates by grouping on all the columns and inserting this into a temp table. Then deleting from the main table and inserting the data from the temp table.

However there are some further values that should not be in the table which I am unsure of how to remove.

So below is an example of my data. So for each name and dateFac there should be only one value for a factor, not two like we have for bbb_u

```
 factor    value     name       dateFac
 bbb       -0.25     John       2017-01-01
 bbb_u     -0.295    John       2017-01-01
 bbb_u     -0.25     John       2017-01-01
```

The bbb_u factor which has the same value as factor bbb is the row I wish to remove so my table should look like below,

```
 factor    value     name       dateFac
 bbb       -0.25     John       2017-01-01
 bbb_u     -0.295    John       2017-01-01
```

**update**

the rule which I need to use to determine which bbb_u row to delete is simply the one which has the same value as the bbb factor.

Comment: will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117659/remove-duplicate-records-except-the-first-record-in-sql

Comment: I'm not sure how that helps?

Comment: k then add more sample data & expected output from which we could derive the solutions.

Comment: Do you always want to keep the lowest `value` in the event of duplicates on `name` and `dateFac`?

Comment: what is the general rule why you chose `bbb   -0.25   John   2017-01-01` over the `bbb_u` row? alphabetically?

Comment: grouping by all columns and then inserting to sample data? You might as well have used `SELECT DISTINCT`

Comment: It would really help if you provide a sample data for your table with duplicate values. Don't do the inserting to a temp table yet, just the raw data.

Comment: Sorry I just updated my question with the rule I am using to select which factor i want to remove

Comment: @GeomanYabes the data above is an example of my problem. The issue is that I have two bbb_u rows and that both have different values so select distinct won't work.

Comment: so again, how do you choose which data to keep?

Comment: its in the update section of my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156253/discussion-between-geoman-yabes-and-mhelpme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are looking something like as below :

```
;WITH CTE
     AS (
     SELECT factor,
            value,
            name,
            dateFac,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VALUE ORDER BY FACTOR) rn
     FROM <tablename>)
     SELECT factor,
            value,
            name,
            dateFac
     FROM CTE
     WHERE RN = 1;
```

**Desired Result :**

```
 factor    value     name       dateFac
 bbb       -0.25     John       2017-01-01
 bbb_u     -0.295    John       2017-01-01
```