# How to remove duplicates via a select if there are two deciding columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table which looks similar to the below.

[image: Table Example]

I'm trying to select data where the row isn't a duplicate. For example, Row ID 1 and 2 are duplicates of each other as the PersonID and Location are the same. In this case, I'd only like to select one of these rows back. However, with rows 4 and 5, I'd like both of these returning as the location is different. How would I go about this?

Comment: _Specify_ the expected result as well. (Formatted text, please. No images.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select min(id) as id, personid, location
from t
group by personid, location;
```

Comment: Bang on the money as always Gordon, thanks. I'll accept the answer in 8 minutes, you were too quick!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE for this as well.
The CTE will allow for you to add another column ranking your records; once you have that ranking you can filter them all out, delete them or do whatever else you need.

I've answered a similar question with regards to deleting duplicates in a similar scenario; see the answer here: [Remove duplicate records except the first record in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117659/remove-duplicate-records-except-the-first-record-in-sql/46117842#46117842)

In your case, the query would be something along the lines of:

```
;WITH NoDuplicates as (
    SELECT 
         PersonID
        ,[Location]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonID ,[Location] ORDER BY PersonID) ranked
    FROM #myTable
)
DELETE
FROM NoDuplicates
WHERE ranked = 1;
```